# Including css and js files in symfony 2.5

Tags: php, html, twig, symfony-2.5

I am working with symfony 2.5 and while including the css and js files although they seem to work but when i check the source in browser i see multiple css and js files being included where as i only included them once. This is what my `header.html.twig` looks like

```
{% block head %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Home | Flat Theme</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets '@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/prettyPhoto.css') }}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/animate.css') }}/">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/main.css') }}"/>
            {% endstylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block topjavascripts %}
            {% javascripts '@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/default/js/html5shiv.js') }}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/default/js/respond.min.js') }}"></script>
            {% endjavascripts %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
{% endblock %}
<body>
```

Here is the source i see in browser and you will notice each css and js file has been mentioned over 5 times.

I tried removing the `@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/css/*` from `{% stylesheets '@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}` but doing that removes all the style

What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% block head %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Home | Flat Theme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/prettyPhoto.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/animate.css') }}/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/default/css/main.css') }}"/>

    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/default/js/html5shiv.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/default/js/respond.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
{% endblock %}
<body>
```

Or, if you don't want to call each file explicitly, try this:

```
{% block head %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Home | Flat Theme</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets 'bundles/default/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block topjavascripts %}
        {% javascripts '@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
{% endblock %}
<body>
```

Comment: i improved one of the solution you provided regarding CSS although your solution of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>` works but this causes the problem with images being used via CSS so i improved it a bit by updating your answer, this is what i edited `{% stylesheets 'bundles/default/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}` once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty funny

```
           {% stylesheets '@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
```

using that you're telling the template engine to iterate all the css in the assets directory, and adding all the `<link/>` to them, that's why they repeat times the assets

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:
(http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig)

You can also include assets located in your bundles' Resources/public folder. You will need to run the php app/console assets:install target [--symlink] command, which moves (or symlinks) files into the correct location. (target is by default "web").

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files

To include JavaScript files, use the javascripts tag in any template:

```
{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
 <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Including CSS Stylesheets:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Notice that in the original example that included JavaScript files, you referred to the files using a path like @AppBundle/Resources/public/file.js, but that in this example, you referred to the CSS files using their actual, publicly-accessible path: bundles/app/css. You can use either, except that there is a known issue that causes the cssrewrite filter to fail when using the @AppBundle syntax for CSS Stylesheets.